# Java Heap Space error in R

Tags: java, r, heap-memory

I am getting the

> OutOfMemoryError (Java): Java Heap Space

error repeatedly. I checked online and tried using command options (`java.parameters="-Xmx2g"`). Also, I have tried other Gigs like 4, 8, 1.5 etc, and nothing seems to work.

Is there a way to check if the command of changing the heap space actually works? I know that `xlcMemoryReport` doesn't actually show you the amount of RAM you have allocated.

Comment: By default R does not use Java. Which package do you use which exhibits this behaviour?

Comment: Hi @GáborBakos thank you for the response.  I used these two packages: XLConnect and rJava. Any advice on what can be done?

Comment: @PABLO G You should add your actual code to the question. Try looking into the `XLConnect` functions `xlcMemoryReport` and `xlcFreeMemory`.

Comment: Is the "g" recognized?  Try "m" at the end.  You can increase the memory available to java in the options (in R). Typically like this:
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1000m")

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set it before you load any packages, described here:

https://support.snowflake.net/s/article/solution-using-r-the-following-error-is-returned-javalangoutofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded

and here

[R Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624002/r-error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space)