# Error in .jcall(cellBlock$ref, "V", setDataMethod, as.integer(j - 1L), : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: r

My result of a model in R says that

```
Error in .jcall(cellBlock$ref, "V", setDataMethod, as.integer(j - 1L),  : 
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Could you please tell me what should I do for solving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This can mostly solved by reserving some arbitrary high amount of memory before loading the `rjava` package or `xlsx`.

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx4096m")
library(xlsx)
```

Sometimes this works fine, sometimes you need to restart the r session to make it work again. Somehow this is an issue with the garbage collection within java if to many functions are called in a to short amount of time. Couldn't solve it 100% until now :-(

EDIT:
Regarding to this article, I already explained that it is important that the java settings are set before loading any package and also by adding another garbage collector. [R Error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624002/r-error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space)

```
options(java.parameters = c("-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC", "-Xmx8192m"))
```

So adding this line as the first line in the script, after restarting the r session, I've never had problems so far.