# bartMachine in caret train error : incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r, dataframe, r-caret

I encounter a strange problem when trying to train a model in R using caret :

```
> bart <- train(x = cor_data, y = factor(outcome), method = "bartMachine")
Error in tuneGrid[!duplicated(tuneGrid), , drop = FALSE] : 
 nombre de dimensions incorrect
```

However, when using `rf`, `xgbTree`, `glmnet`, or `svmRadial` instead of `bartMachine`, no error is raised.
Moreover, `dim(cor_data)` and `length(outcome)` return `[1] 3056  134` and `[1] 3056` respectively, which indicates that there is indeed no issue with the dimensions of my dataset.

I have tried changing the `tuneGrid` parameter in `train`, which resolved the problem but caused this issue instead :

```
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "pool-89-thread-1"
```

My dataset includes no NA, and all variables are either numerical or binary.

My goal is to extract the most important variables in the `bart` model. For example, I use for random forests:

```
rf <- train(x = cor_data, y = factor(outcome), method = "rf")
rfImp <- varImp(rf)
rf_select <- row.names(rfImp$importance[order(- rfImp$importance$Overall)[1:43], , drop = FALSE])
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Ok.. so the issue is with java, I suggest updating your question since you solved the issue with tuneGrid, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624002/r-error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space

Answer (score 0):

Since your goal is to extract the most important variables in the bart model, I will assume you are willing to bypass the caret wrapper and do it directly in R bartMachine, which is the only way I could successfully run it.

For my system, solving the memory issue required 2 further things:

1. Restart R and before loading anything, allocate 8Gb memory as so:

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8g")
```

2. When running bartMachineCV, turn off `mem_cache_for_speed`:

```
library(bartMachine)
set_bart_machine_num_cores(16)
bart <- bartMachineCV(X = cor_data, y = factor(outcome), mem_cache_for_speed = F)
```

This will iterate through 3 values of k (2, 3 and 5) and 2 values of m (50 and 200) running 5 cross-validations each time, then builds a bartMachine using the best hyperparameter combination. You may also have to reduce the number of cores depending on your system, but this took about an hour on a 20,000 observation x 12 variable training set on 16 cores. You could also reduce the number of hyperparameter combinations it tests using the k_cvs and num_tree_cvs arguments.

Then to get the variable importance:

```
 vi <- investigate_var_importance(bart, num_replicates_for_avg = 20)
print(vi)
```

You can also use it as a predictive model with `predict(bart, new_data=new)` similar to the object normally returned by `caret::train()`. This worked on R4.0.5, bartMachine_1.2.6 and rJava_1.0-4