# Trouble with read.xlsx in R

Tags: r, xlsx

I am currently attempting to use R to read a (large, 8.3 MB) .xlsx file into a matrix. I am attempting to do so with the read.xlsx file in the xlsx package. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/index.html

I am now trying to read the contents of one of the sheets in the file with the following command:

```
sheetname<-read.xlsx("/Users/jinkinsonsmith/Downloads/Re _Introduction/filename.xlsx",sheetName='sheetname')
```

It looks like this command should work in terms of reading the contents of sheet "sheetname" in xlsx file "filename" into the vector "sheetname". However, instead, I am getting this error message:

> Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod",
> cl,  : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

It seems like I'm not the first person to get this error message (example: [How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error)), but even after reading the other post I just linked it is still not clear to me what I should do to fix this error. My MacBook Pro has long had issues with running out of disk space and requiring me to delete a bunch of files, so that could be the culprit, but it is also apparently possible that I have too many stored references to objects in R that I no longer use and that are taking up too much space. In the latter case I don't know how I would remove any unneeded references.

Comment: You can change to `R` in `64bits` mode.

Comment: Have you tried any of the other packages for reading  XL files? excel.link,  readexcel, readxlsb, XLCONNECT perhaps.    Javaheapspace is RAM, not disk.   Consider also reading a specified number of rows and repeating the call for the next set of rows, etc.

Comment: Try the `read_xlsx` from the  `openxlsx` package. It does not rely on java as package `xlsx` does.

Comment: @PaulvanOppen I assume you mean "read.xlsx", rather than "read_xlsx", which appears to be part of the "readxl" package not the "openxlsx" package. Good news: read.xlsx worked!

Comment: Yes, you are correct: `read.xlsx`

Answer (score 0):

By using the following line of code **before** you load any other package, I could solve similar problems like this. I already described it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624002/r-error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space).

```
options(java.parameters = c("-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC", "-Xmx8192m"))
library(xlsx)
```

Please add this line and restart, since other packages can load some java things by themselves and the options have to be set **before any Java is loaded**.

In general, these option change the type of garbage collection which sometimes makes problems in the default settings and also increases the memory to 8GB.