# R furrr plan returns errors when trying to tweak the multisession plan?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, furrr

I am trying to set the plan I need but I am getting the following errors:

```
no_cores <- availableCores() - 2
plan(multisession, workers = no_cores, lazy = T, gc = T)
```

and the error is:

```
Error in MultisessionFuture(expr = expr, envir = envir, substitute = FALSE,  : 
  argument "expr" is missing, with no default
```

or:

```
plan(multisession, workers = no_cores, lazy = T, gc = T)
Error in tweak.future(function (expr, envir = parent.frame(), substitute = TRUE,  : 
  Future argument 'lazy' must not be tweaked / set via plan()
```

Please advise how can I set the `workers`, `lazy`, `gc` and other parameters of `multisession`/`multicore`  plans.

My R version is:

```
R.Version()
$platform
[1] "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "linux-gnu"

$system
[1] "x86_64, linux-gnu"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "4"

$minor
[1] "0.2"

$year
[1] "2020"

$month
[1] "06"

$day
[1] "22"

$`svn rev`
[1] "78730"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)"

$nickname
[1] "Taking Off Again"
```

Comment: @akrun, maybe you can help?

Answer (score 2):

Trying your example I've got the second error message. And I've basically followed the advice given: you set the argument `lazy = T` in `plan` which is not allowed. However, you can set this argument directly in the `furrr` function call:

```
library(furrr)
no_cores <- availableCores() - 2
plan(multisession, workers = no_cores, gc = T)

future_map(c("hello", "world"), ~.x,
           .options = future_options(lazy = TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] "hello"

[[2]]
[1] "world"
```

Comment: I have a very big dataframe and for some reason I am getting 
```Error in .jnew("opennlp.tools.postag.POSModel", .jcast(.jnew("java.io.FileInputStream",  : 
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space```

But I have set: ```options(java.parameters = "-Xmx8000m")```

Comment: This sounds like you don't have enough RAM. Have you monitored the memory usage? Also, maybe it helps to check out the [advice here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624002/r-error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space)

Comment: Maybe there are ways to split up your data, so only use a part of the df for every calculation; or depending which calculations you make do you need to always pass the complete df or only some rows/columns of it?

Comment: I have 1M+ rows in my tibble and I need to process all of them using some functions.
When I am using htop on Ubuntu 18.04 it shows it gets to around 7.5GB out of 16GB RAM and fails with java heap size error.

If it's ok with you we can make a zoom and post it the results later here.

Comment: have you tried setting the java options before loading rJava and maybe use more than 8GB for the java heap? sorry, I'm not available for zoom

Comment: sure it's now 10gb before all the libraries loads.
I mean at the start of the whole program I have the options(java.parameters = "-Xmx10000m")

I have 2 Javas installed 8 and 11, and 2 rJava libraries in my packages tab, maybe this is the reason?

Comment: There's no reproducible code but note that **rJava** objects cannot be exported to parallel workers.  See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/vignettes/future-4-non-exportable-objects.html for an example.  This is true regardless what parallel framework you use in R.

Comment: Thanks for the package and the clarification Henrik! So in order to parallelise the code you would need to initialise the rJava objects on every worker?